# Kite not finding pythonpath libraries, although python does

Tags: python, vim, kite

I checked Kite documentation but could not understand if Kite only (it is already a great tool) covers core main - core libraries or if it is expected to find and support also personal libraries, for example libraries in pythonpath.

In case, suggestions on how to add them?

Using Anaconda and VIM on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recently released a new feature for this, and have published [help docs](https://help.kite.com/article/97-adding-libraries-from-pythonpath-to-the-kite-index) that we'll continue updating. Here are the instructions for how you can add libraries to Kite's directory so you're sure it indexes them.

(We're debugging some aspects of this, so let us know if you run into issues or have further questions.)

First, make the /libraries directory in the .kite directory if it's not already there:

```
mkdir -p ~/.kite/libraries/
```

Next, create a symbolic link to the library you want indexed by Kite:

```
ln -s /your_lib_dir/ ~/.kite/libraries/
```

Finally, check the link is there:

```
cd .kite/
ls libraries/your_lib_dir/
```

Kite will then be able to index those specified libraries.

Comment: thank you very much, don't want to rush you guys with the documentation. The `libraries' folder is already present as you indicated, good. Is Kite looking recursively, could I sym link the main module folder? I'm trying now, it doesn't work at the moment but I don't have experience with sym linking, so it likely is my fault. I'll keep up update. Are you thinking about automatically taking the paths from the pythonpath?

Comment: all good! We're working on the documentation now. It will be updated here: https://help.kite.com/article/97-adding-libraries-from-pythonpath-to-the-kite-index

Comment: Given privacy concerns of users, we built Kite to be cautious in its search for libraries. This means Kite explicitly avoids searching through Linux directories that are hidden (e.g. contain `/.`), and the directories starting with the following: `/usr`, `/dev`, `/tmp`, `/opt`, `/sbin`.

It could be the case that your `PYTHONPATH` is set to a directory Kite does not walk to find libraries. (If not the case, please let us know so we can debug/ further clarify! Email us: support [at] kite.com)

For example: `PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`

Comment: Finally, to answer your question about looking recursively, once the `site-packages` folder is symbolically linked, Kite remembers it as a location for libraries and includes it in its recurring index builds.

We’ll continue to improve upon this feature, so more feedback welcomed!